# Facing Problem in fetching reports using xero api in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, xero-api

I am facing problem in fetching reports using xero api. I also fetched invoices and accounts but when I fetch reports then I get error as mentioned in catch block.
Here is code what I have tried.

```node
app.get("/reports", async function(req, res) {
    try {
        const accessToken = req.session.accessToken;
        await xero.setTokenSet(accessToken);

        const apiResponse = await xero.accountingApi.getReportTrialBalance(
          req.session.xeroTenantId
        );

        res.send({ invoices: apiResponse.body });
    } catch (err) {
        res.send("Sorry, something went wrong");
    }
});
```

Comment: print the `err` and see what is exactly the error

Comment: error is title: 'Unauthorized',
       status: 401,
    detail: 'AuthorizationUnsuccessful',

Comment: @Subburaj but this error only comes at time of fetching reports otherwise it runs perfectly with other get functions